# FX Tag Special Characters in Field Name

Tags: xml, fxml

I have a simple xml file which is used to auto populate PDF form fields with values held in the xml. Im having issues with any form filed name\reference that includes a special character such as brackets, underscore etc.

Is there a specific way to reference special characters?

The below fields import the data into the PDF fine

```
<fxTag xfdf:original="ForenamesPD">Sample</fxTag>
<fxTag xfdf:original="SurnamePD">Sample</fxTag>
```

PDF showing import successful from XML:
[image]

However the following does not work at all:

```
<fxTag xfdf:original="Teacher Reference Number (if applicable)">Sample</fxTag>
```

Unfortunately I cannot change the form field name as i did not create the PDF.

The below screenshot shows the name of the form field i am trying to add to:
[image]

I'm guessing there is some way to reference special characters but I'm not sure on this?